# How does QGIS 3.2.3 handle or create spatial indexes within a geopackage?

Tags: qgis, gdal, sqlite, geopackage

My frame of reference is:

[Does QGIS automatically use spatialite spatial indexes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107594/does-qgis-automatically-use-spatialite-spatial-indexes)
This explain that QGIS uses `QgsSpatiaLiteFeatureIterator` for Spatialite Data Provider

[Spatial indexes in GeoPackage files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280696/spatial-indexes-in-geopackage-files)
This explain the use of Query that is utilizing r-tree index with sub-query:

[Creating Spatial Index for Geopackage using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265434/creating-spatial-index-for-geopackage-using-qgis)

This last one explain that It's possible in QGIS3 to create spatial index for Geopackage. You can click "Create Spatial index" from the Layer Properties Dialog and that's it.

My doubt when reading all this, is what is the current state of the use of spatial index within a geopackage?.

Because I can use the DBmanager to create non-spatial indexes within a geopackage per column, and they are visible inside the DBmanager information window, however when using "Create Spatial index from the Layer Properties" QGIS seems to create the index -very fast by the way-, but the geopackage is not altered with any new table related to the layer.

And I can not see information in the DBmanager that the index was created.

In fact, when creating an index within the geopackage, only the option to create non-spatial indexes is possible, the option to create a spatial index appears gray/disabled.

When one creates the index from the properties of the layer, QGIS saves it inside the project but not inside the geopackage? Is this how it works?

Why is it not possible to create spatial indexes for geopackages using the DBmanager?

I'm just trying to understand the operation of the gpkg within QGIS

use QGIS 3.2.3
Data: geopackage with 2 tables
table to nonspatial: 4 million records
spatial b table: polygons approx 40k elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a new GeoPackage layer you can select if spatial index is created or not from the advanced options

[image]

If you want to add the index later goto layer properties and press the button

[image]

I could not find any way to check with QGIS if spatial index exists or not. The index is stored into virtual layer that is named as **[rtree][tablename][geometry column]** and you can use any SQLite capable application and see if the table is there.

[image]

Ogrinfo belongs to SQLite capable applications and spatial index exists if this command prints some ogrfeatures on screen

```
ogrinfo indextest.gpkg -sql "select * from sqlite_master where type='table' and name like 'rtree_indextest%' LIMIT 1"
```

Result:

```
Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
type: String (0.0)
name: String (0.0)
tbl_name: String (0.0)
rootpage: Integer64 (0.0)
sql: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  type (String) = table
  name (String) = rtree_indextest_geometry
  tbl_name (String) = rtree_indextest_geometry
  rootpage (Integer64) = 0
  sql (String) = CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "rtree_indextest_geometry" USING rtree(id, minx, maxx, miny, m
axy)
```

**EDIT** GDAL supports nowadays also a more simple SQL for checking if the spatial index exists or not. Documentation:

```
> Starting with GDAL 2.2, the
> “HasSpatialIndex(‘table_name’,’geom_col_name’)” statement can be used
> for checking if the table has spatial index on the named geometry
> column.

Usage example:

ogrinfo indextest.gpkg -sql "select HasSpatialIndex('test_table','geom')"
...
Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
HasSpatialIndex: Integer (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  HasSpatialIndex (Integer) = 1
```

Value 0 means no/false and value 1 yes/true.

Comment: There is a bug/feature request which - if I am reading correctly - has disabled the 'Create Spatial Index' buttons from DB Manager and Properties GUI, and those will only be available if its a SpatiaLite database.       https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44513

Comment: I am not sure what is the current situation. The GPKG driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html has that support nowadays "The following functions, with identical syntax and semantics as in Spatialite, are also available :
CreateSpatialIndex(table_name String, geom_column_name String): creates a spatial index (RTree) on the specified table/geometry column"

Comment: Yer its a discussion for another thread. Just for now, i think its worthwhile mentioning that the 'Create Spatial Index' button is greyed out on a gpkg. Also in DB Manager, the Create Spatial Index button is not available for gpkg. (QGIS 3.22)

Comment: I made a test with QGIS 3.28.2 and for me the Create Spatial Index button is greyed out if the table already has a spatial index. The button is active if the table does not have spatial index.

Comment: I also added an easier ogrinfo syntax for checking if spatial index exists.